# Recode a factor variable, dropping N/A

Tags: r, dplyr, recode, levels

I have a factor variable with 14 levels, which I'm trying to into collapse into only 3 levels. It contains two N/A which I also wanna remove.

My code looks like this:

`job <- fct_collapse(E$occupation, other = c("7","9", "10", "13" "14"), 1 = c("1", "2", "3", "12"), 2 = c("4", "5", "6", "8", "11"))`

However it just gives me tons of error. Can anyone help here me here?

Answer (score 1):

We could also this with a named `list`

```
library(forcats)
lst1 <- setNames(list(as.character(c(7, 9, 10, 13, 14)), 
   as.character(c(1, 2, 3, 12)), as.character(c(4, 5, 6, 8, 11))), c('other', 1, 2))
fct_collapse(df$occupation, !!!lst1)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(occupation = c("1", "3", "5", "7", "9", "10", 
"12", "14", "13", "4", "7", "6", "5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Answer (score 0):

For numbers try using backquotes in `fct_collapse`.

```
job <- forcats::fct_collapse(df$occupation, 
                             other = c("7","9", "10", "13", "14"), 
                              `1` = c("1", "2", "3", "12"), 
                              `2` = c("4", "5", "6", "8", "11"))
```